# Recognize dark rectangles with Open CV - Node.js

Tags: node.js, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm trying to do some image recognition using Open CV. I want to detect the position of a dark rectangle in a game called Diablo 2.

After detecting the position of the rectangle, I will extract the text of that rectangle using OCR.

I've prepared some examples using Photoshop of where are those rectangles located. 
On the left you can see the game screenshot, on the right I've pointed out the dark rectangles using a red rectangle, that's the place I want to detect using OpenCV.

[image: Diablo 2 - Rectangle recognition]

Which OpenCV method should I use to detect those dark rectangles?

I'm not sure if Open CV is capable of doing this kind of pattern recognition, would be great if anyone can point me out how to do it.

Comment: You can try binary thresholding the image and then use HoghLines detector to filter out any rectangle type formation.

Comment: Can you capture an image of the background, without the black text box? If so, then you can subtract the background from your new image (with text box) .

Comment: I've been able to isolate the rectangle of the area that I want to process. However, using findContours gives me hundres of small rectangles, but instead I just want only one of them. Not sure how to continue .You can see the result here: https://i.imgur.com/dB6HoYG.png